# Best temporary solution for a cracked single pane window

Tags: windows, crack, old-house

History/Problem: This question is pretty much a duplicate of [Old single pane House window has a crack, can I fix it using a resin?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182885/old-single-pane-house-window-has-a-crack-can-i-fix-it-using-a-resin) however this is for an old house where the entire window needs repaired. But that is a long term plan due to money. The problem is that [we have bought interior storm windows](https://indowwindows.com/solutions/insulating-drafty-windows/) (Indow), but they do not hold up to strong gusts of wind that come through the cracks (there are multiple windows in this state :( ). So, I am trying to fill the gaps to keep the outside from blowing in. Add to it that this is a curved glass, so replacement gets even more complicated at this time.

Question: Per the related question, the accepted answer from @jphi1618 makes sense. But, in the interim what is my best solution to keep it from getting worse and to keep the elements out? I think a two part epoxy is likely best (I was thinking something like [Gorilla epoxy](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gorilla-0-85-fl-oz-Epoxy-42001/100670610#overlay)), but would just using tape on both interior and exterior work? If I am being realistic, the full repair of all the windows could be 2-3 years out, so I would need something to last a few years.

Comment: Not many tapes hold up to weather.  Wind blowing in, there are spray foam gap fillers for windows/doors that will help.  If coming in though the glass and window frame, caulking is your friend.  Can you explain about interior storm windows?  Is that the thin plastic you heat to smooth/tighten up or real windows?

Comment: I added a link and note that it is Indow, which seems to be specialized plexi with a gasket like outside so it can squeeze in (but it does not hold up to gusts). The crack is in the middle of the window for most, so spray foam is pretty unsightly - thus why I was thinking epoxy - I just don't want to somehow make it worse. I know there is risk in general, but something is better than leaving it...

Comment: The spray foam goes between the window frame and the wall to stop drafts.

Comment: Clear packing tape inside and out. If it lasts a long time, great. If it doesn't, you've spent very little on it (and still have the rest of the roll for packing boxes.)

Comment: OK, but that is not my question - it is about the crack in the glass. That is where the biggest drafts are currently.

Comment: If only you gave us pictures...

Answer (score 0):

I think after further research I have determined for myself that while tape is a good, cheap solution. Using epoxy is the better one with the caveat that you need to be extremely careful to not over-exert pressure while applying or else you could make the crack worse. So, gently filling it is the best path - and I am figuring that if it does not fill fully because of the need for being gentle then I can attack it from the outside as well - and also reinforce further with some tape :).

My top references for this decision:

- https://www.kcwindowandglass.com/post/steps-to-handling-window-crack-damage-sea-tac
- https://www.architecturaldigest.com/reviews/windows/how-to-fix-a-cracked-window
- https://www.glassgenius.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-diy-fix-cracked-window-glass-at-your-home/